# EEL Program built with pyinstaller stops server (leaving the chromium window, but stopping server)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, eel

I'm making my chat application. When i run the source code, it works. But when i try to use my EXE, (all files exist in the run directory) It launches Chromium (in --app mode with my page), but after a few seconds, the server stops. Here is my code:

```py
import eel
import eel.browsers
import os
from time import sleep
import win10toast_persist as w10toast



toaster = w10toast.ToastNotifier()


my_env = os.environ
my_env['GOOGLE_API_KEY'] = 'no'
my_env['GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID'] = 'no'
my_env['GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'no'

eel.browsers.set_path('chrome', 'chromium/chrome.exe')


# initializing the application  
eel.init(f'{os.getcwd()}\\mhat')  

@eel.expose
def notif(title, message):
    toaster.show_toast(
        title,
        message,
        duration = 3,
        icon_path = "icon.ico",
    )
def close_callback(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

eel.start('index.html', size=(600, 430), block=True, on_close=close_callback)
```

Here is my index.html:

```html
<script src="/eel.js"></script>

<script>
    if (localStorage.getItem('username') === null || localStorage.getItem('password') === null) {
        window.location.replace('/login.html')

    }
    else {
        window.location.replace('/app.html')
    }

</script>
```

And also, in the login.html, if WebSocket disconnects, it sets the app HTML to this:

```py
<p>You have been disconnected. Press the button down below to try reconnecting.</p>
<br><button class='btn' onclick='window.location.reload()'>Reconnect</button>`
```

And also, "window.location.replace" function is used not only in the index.html file.

I've tried:

Building the app with this command:
`pyinstaller -F main.py --icon icon.ico`

Building the app with this command:
~pyinstaller -F main.py --icon icon.ico --hidden-import bottle_websocket --add-data C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\eel\eel.js;eel`

Building the app with this command:
`python -m eel main.py mhat -F --icon "icon.ico"`

But unsuccessfull.